# making paging without refreshing in mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

i wanna make some thing like this ( << 1 2 3 4 >> ) end of my view . i used HTML.BeginForm and it worked .but i had post back.so i changed HTML.BeginForm to Ajax.BeginForm , now it dose not work.

for example when i click on link 2 i get this error in fire bug :

```
"  NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/myAction/search? numberpage=2"
```

or on linke 1 :

```
"  NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/myAction/search? numberpage=1"
```

view :

```
         @using (Ajax.BeginForm( "search ","MyAction",new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = ""
        }))
        {
      int page = (int)ViewBag.page;
      int pages = (int)ViewBag.pages;

     <div class="pagination pagination-left">
    <ul>
        <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("«", "MyAction", new { numberpage = pages })</li>
        @{for (int i = pages; i >= 1; i--)
          {
              if (i == page)
              {
            <li class="active">@HtmlAjax.ActionLink(i.ToString(), " MyAction ",  new { numberpage = i })</li>
              }
              else
              {
            <li>@Ajax.ActionLink(i.ToString(), " MyAction ", new { numberpage =  i  })</li>
              }
          }
        }
        <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("»", " MyAction ", new { numberpage = 1 })</li>

    </ul>


</div>
```

my controller :

```
[HttpPOST]
   public ActionResult search(int? numberpage)
   {
    int skip = 0;
   ViewBag.page ;
  Temp= myobjectclass.GetAll().tolist();
   ViewBag.pages = (Temp.Count() / 5) + 1;

   var db = new ProjectContext();

   var obj = new projectClass.myobjectclass();
   if (numberpage!= null)
   {
       skip = 5 * (numberpage.Value - 1);
       ViewBag.page = numberpage.Value;

   }
   obj.StudentRequierments = Temp.Skip(skip).Take(5).ToList();
   ViewBag.pages = (Temp.Count() / 5) + 1;

   return View(obj)
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Also, I notice you're passing a param called pagenumber but your method takes a param named numberpage.

Comment: no , i wrote wrong , i eddited.when i click on any link (1,2, >> , <<) any thing accour . and in consol tab in fire bug i get above error .

Comment: There is a space in your querystring, if you remove it, can you access the page? `http://localhost/myAction/search? numberpage=2`

Comment: no no , i wrote this sentence by hand . so there is space.

Comment: i have a html.beginform with post method . there is  this ajax part into html.beginform . it may be because of it?

Comment: my friends no one know?

Comment: see this : http://en.webdiyer.com/MvcPager